# Cannot draw wind vectors using quiver in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I was trying to plot wind vectors using quiver in Python, I was getting an error of

> TypeError: Argument 'x' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray,
>   got DataArray)

How to resolve this issue?

My code is

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

#%% u wind import
fname='/home/SIMS/P1/uwind/*.nc'
du=xr.open_mfdataset(fname)
uwnd=du.uwnd
uwind=du.mean('time')

#%% v wind import
fname='/home/SIMS/P1/vwind/*.nc'                                        
dv=xr.open_mfdataset(fname)
#ds=xr.open_mfdataset(fname,concat_dim="time")                     
vwnd=dv.vwnd
vwind=dv.mean('time')

lat = du.uwind.lat
lon = du.uwind.lon
u=uwind.uwnd[0,:,:]
v=vwind.vwnd[0,:,:] 

print(lat.shape)
print(lon.shape)
print(u.shape)
print(v.shape)

lon,lat = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=80.0, min_latitude=-10.0, 
max_latitude=20.0, globe=None, latitude_true_scale=0.0))
ax.coastlines()
ax.coastlines()
ax.quiver(lat,lon,u,v)
plt.show()
```

the shape of lat,lon, u and v as follows

> (15,)
>
> (73,)
>
> (15, 73)
>
> (15, 73)

lon

> lon Out[192]:  array([[ 50. ,  52.5,  55. , ..., 225. , 227.5, 230. ],
>          [ 50. ,  52.5,  55. , ..., 225. , 227.5, 230. ],
>          [ 50. ,  52.5,  55. , ..., 225. , 227.5, 230. ],
>          ...,
>          [ 50. ,  52.5,  55. , ..., 225. , 227.5, 230. ],
>          [ 50. ,  52.5,  55. , ..., 225. , 227.5, 230. ],
>          [ 50. ,  52.5,  55. , ..., 225. , 227.5, 230. ]], dtype=float32)

It is plotting blank image without any wind vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I tried with .values for lon,lat,u and v, I could plot it.

```
lat = du.uwnd.lat.values
lon = du.uwnd.lon.values
u=anomaly_u.uwnd.values[0,:,:]
v=anomaly_v.vwnd.values[0,:,:]
```